# Porting python PKCS1_v1_5 encryption code to java but java code not work

Tags: python, java, rsa

I have a backend,which receives codes and returns true or false.
I send it codes using my python encryption,it returns true(the result varible):

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
import base64

prsa = RSA.importKey('''-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----''')
pcipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(prsa)
result=base64.b64encode(pcipher.encrypt(bytes))
```

But my java encryption always return false:

```
public static String encrypt(byte[] bytes, String publicKeyFilePath)
    throws Exception {
  byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(publicKeyFilePath));
  X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
  KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
  Key key = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
  cipher.init(1, key);
  byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
  return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result);
}
```

Both java and python codes can be well decrypted by my java decryption codes(I have private key).
I have tryed different kinds of cipher,such as:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");
```

And trying to set provider:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding",new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

But all return false.I am confused about the "PKCS1_v1_5",for don't know which kind of padding it is,and what is the right code porting to java?

Comment: I don't see any difference, the padding mode is compatible between Python & Java. Likely the results differ because the resulting ciphertext is randomized. Are you sure that you are not running into problems during communication? You are not using base64url, for instance. ECB is a misnomer, RSA doesn't use block cipher modes, basically ECB and None (not defined in the provider by Sun / Oracle) are identical - using BC or not should not make any difference (functionally anyway).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for your reply.There shuld be no communicate problems since my Python codes work fine.It is true that the resulting ciphertext is randomized,both in python and java,so I can only know my java codes go wrong by backend's reply.I try to change base64 to base64url,but it still not works.If the padding is right,I dont't know where my fault is...

Comment: Well, the only other option that I can think of is that your key management is confused really. I'm also thinking about strange public exponents, but I cannot get issues with those connected with your observations.

Comment: I see that the public key format used in python is PKCS1, and PEM encoded at that. This is not compatible with Java's `X509EncodedKeySpec` class, and if you attempt to use such a key you'll receive an `InvalidKeySpecException`. So what do you do with such an exception?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Actually my java code is using .der format public key,which is exported from python,so I do not catch an exception.